# Data recovery for another user?

Tags: backup, time-machine, data-recovery

I'm attempting to recover data from an external drive used as a Time Machine backup for a now deceased user.  The Mac that it was attached to is now long gone.  My first attempt lets me generally read the disk, but I'm locked out of the individual user documents folders.  This is a business device and I do have administrator passwords, but I'm uncertain on the correct approach to gain access to those folders.

Is there a way to successfully gain access to this data and how do I do it?

Comment: See if you can right click on folder, click on `Get Info` under Sharing & Permissions get yourself read access.

Comment: Does not work.  It accepts my admin password when I hit the padlock there.  Any changes I make to the permissions just vanish as I'm making them.  If I ignore that and try to access anyways I still get the permission error.

Comment: Can you try accessing it via Terminal, using `sudo` wherever required.

Comment: Oddly, Terminal, even without sudo, is letting me access a large number of files that the Finder won't let me...

Comment: If you can read the files, I’d suggest copying them over to your home directory and changing ownership to yourself.

Comment: We’re you able to successfully access the data?

Comment: Yes, through a combination of Get Info/set permissions and copying from the CLI I was able to get what I needed.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by  clicking on the folder, select **Get Info** under **Sharing & Permissions** and grant yourself read permission.

Try to access the folder via Terminal. Use `sudo` if required.

If you can read the files this way, copy them over to your home directory and change the ownership to yourself using `chown` command.

You should be able to gain access to the files this way.